# how to delete mysql records with jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have been at this all day trying to use jquery to delete a mysql record. I was following this tutorial http://davidwalsh.name/animated-ajax-jquery and after many hours I am unsuccessful. Blow is my php/mysql code to connect and display data. Can someone show me how to integrate the two scripts so that i am also able to delete records?

```
$dbhost = "";
$dbuser = "";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "";
$dbtable ="";

$connect = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);

if (!$connect) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db($dbname, $connect);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $dbtable");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo '
      <tr class="table odd">
       <td class="sorting">'.$row["name"].'</td>
       <td>'.$row["address"].'</td>
       <td >'.$row["city"].'</td>
       <td >'.$row["zip"].'</td>
       <td >'.$row["id"].'</td>
      </tr>';
  }

mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: Please accept answers to some of your previous questions, others will be more inclined to help if you do.

Comment: thanks you and yes i have done so

Comment: I don't see any jQuery, nor any DELETE command though, in this condition it's difficult to help you on "delete mysql record with jquery". Be careful on implementing that system you linked, the delete part is somewhat lacking any control on what's doing

Comment: Learn how do to this delete operation with a regular form submission server-roundtrip operation, so you can learn the basic mechanics of this, BEFORE jumping into the more advanced ajax waters. If you can't figure out how to do it old-school, don't even TRY to get fancy.

Answer (score 0):

i will build here the html, JQuery, PHP, and Database for this example:

### Database

```html
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
  
INSERT INTO `t1` (`name`) VALUES ('Jhon');
INSERT INTO `t1` (`name`) VALUES ('Bon');
INSERT INTO `t1` (`name`) VALUES ('Jovi');
```

### PHP (db.php):

```html
<?php

$username = 'kmoshe';
$password = 'password';
$host = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'test';

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname",$username, $password
    ,
    array(
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
    ));
```

### index.php

```html
<?php
require_once './db.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>StackOverFlow</title>

    <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
            crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php



$sql = "SELECT * FROM t1";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

while( $row = $stmt->fetch()){
    $id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    ?>
    <div class="row"><span row-id="<?=$id?>"><?=$id?>.</span><span><?=$name?></span></div>
    <?php
 }

?>
</body>
```

### Javascript (app.js):

```js
$(document).ready( function(){

        $(document).on('click','.row', function(e) {

            let $pressedRowID =$(this).children('span').attr('row-id');
            let fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('id', $pressedRowID);

            $.ajax({
                url: "delete.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: fd,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,

                complete: function (results) {
                    try {
                        let str = JSON.parse(results.responseText);
                        window.location.reload();
                        console.log(str)
                    } catch (e) {
                        console.error(e.message);
                    }
                },
            });


        }) ;



});
```

### delete.php:

```html
<?php
require_once './db.php';
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$sql = "DELETE FROM t1 WHERE id = :id";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(['id' => $id]);

echo json_encode("id $id has been deleted");
```